# Scheme Beginner Excercise

Tags: scheme

I'm just picking up on some Scheme for the first time today and I wanted to try and write a few functions that would give me an idea of the basic syntax but for some reason (maybe because of my lack of sleep) it's proving much more difficult than I expected.

first, I want to make a function that displays each item in a list. Essentially I'd give it:

```
(mydisplay '(3 4 "dog" 9)) and it would display those items.
```

Next I'd like to write the an equivalent of this C++ snipet in Scheme:

```
for (int i = 6; i < 25; i+=6)
{
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated! Sorry for the possibly waaaayyy too simple questions but I just can't seem to grasp some of the syntax

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at Lisp for the first time I knew 6 languages and had experienced that learning a new language was very simple. Unfortunately the experience I had wasn't really how to learn a new language since when  I thought I knew 6 languages the truth is that I knew 6 dialects springing from a [common ancestor called Algol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#ALGOL_based).  Perl, Java, C++ are almost the same language and if you know one you know how to do the other within a day.

You need to find yourself a nice book or resource that you can follow and learn Scheme as if you have never ever known a programming language before. You can have a look at the [Rosetta Code for Scheme](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Scheme) to compare how some algorithms are done in Scheme but even if you see the tasks have similar structure they tend to do quite different things.

```scm
;; roll your own using recursion
(define (my-display lst)
  (when (pair? lst)
    (display (car lst))
    (newline)
    (my-display (cdr lst))))

;; one with higher order procedures
(define (my-display lst)
  (for-each (lambda (e) 
              (display e)
              (newline))
            lst))


;; Close to your algol for loop 
(let make-number ((count 6))
  (if (< count 25)
      (begin
        (display count)
        (newline)
        (make-number (+ count 6)))
      'return-value))

;; A better approach 
;; make a list of the numbers based on start end and step
(define (make-range start end step)
  (let rec ((cnt start))
    (if (> cnt end)
        '()
        (cons cnt (rec (+ cnt step))))))

(my-display (make-range 6 25 6)) ; prints the numbers

;; one with higher order procedures
;; uses SRFI-1 List Librarys unfold instead of named let
(define (make-range start end step)
  (unfold (lambda (x) (< end x))
          values
          (lambda (x) (+ x step))
          start))
```

I do not recommend you to use the `do` loop. Use named `let` or higher order procedures and keep the printing part outside.

I really enjoyed the [SICP video lectures](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/). They are a tad old and thus are a older version of Scheme than today, but someone has made [support for it in racket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561746/1565698). When you know one lisp language it's easy to learn [a different dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#Lisp_based), especially a later Scheme report.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. Thanks for the awesome response!

Answer (score 0):

```
> (define (mydisplay xs)
    (for-each (lambda (x) (display x) (newline)) xs))
> (mydisplay '(3 4 "dog" 9))
3
4
dog
9
> (do ((i 6 (+ i 6)))
      ((not (< i 25)))
    (display i) (newline))
6
12
18
24
```

Comment: Thanks! This should help me get a decent start

Answer (score 0):

As you will find out, there are many ways to loop in Scheme. I would start with the most fundamental, namely tail recursive calls.

```
for (int i = 6; i < 25; i+=6)
{
  cout << i << endl;
}

(let loop ([i 6])
  (if (< i 25) 
      (begin
        (display i)
        (newline)
        (loop (+ i 6)))))
```

The construct used above is called a `named let` and you will see it over and over again in Scheme code.

Note that one-armed `if` is used above. If your Scheme implementation has `when` it becomes:

```
(let loop ([i 6])
  (when (< i 25) 
    (display i)
    (newline)
    (loop (+ i 6))))
```