# Using MIT/GNU Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, edwin

I have downloaded the MIT/GNU Scheme implementation of LISP in order to understand *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*. However, I am a bit confused about what I am dealing with when I launch the program. When the program is launched, I get two windows: the "MIT/GNU Scheme" window, and the "Edwin: *scheme*" window.

What are these two windows used for? Is the "MIT/GNU Scheme" one some sort of command-line interpreter? While the other is where code can be written and saved?

Further questions: If the MIT/GNU Scheme is a command-line interpreter, how can I get the "1 ]=>" prompt to show. And if the other is where I write programs, how do I test and save the programs?

Comment: You could use Dr racket

Comment: Someone has made a [SICP compability language for DrRacket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546115/which-lang-packet-is-proper-for-sicp-in-dr-racket/19561746#19561746) and I recommend using DrRacket unless you are familiar with Emacs and console based editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MIT/GNU Scheme` should start off as minimized.  It is just a *background console window* that starts the editor.  You need not pay attention to it (nor can you interact with it).

`Edwin: *scheme*` is the [Edwin](https://gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Edwin.html) *text editor*, which looks to me like some sort of [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) derivative.  It allows you to not only write Scheme scripts but also evaluate Scheme expressions interactively.  However, to do this you will need to learn the appropriate keybindings and commands, and some familiarity with Emacs would certainly help here too.  Therefore I suggest [reading the documentation](https://gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user).