# Use mit-scheme with REPL and editor together

Tags: emacs, scheme, lisp, sicp, mit-scheme

I'm going through [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) course and as recommended installed mit-scheme. I want to use the REPL together with a scheme file. The reason is because I can add scheme code in the file and then run the commands in REPL. What I have works, but the problem is every time I edit the file, I have to quit terminal and reload the file for REPL to see changes.

Is there a way to reload the file easily or some other way for REPL to see changes from the file?

**This my setup:**

1. I installed mit-scheme with `brew install mit-scheme`
2. I have a local file named `code.scm`
3. In terminal, I load the file with `mit-scheme --load /Users/name/Desktop/code.scm`
4. Terminal now starts the REPL and everything works. The problem is that if I add new code to the file `code.scm`, I have to quit terminal and call this again: `mit-scheme --load /Users/name/Desktop/code.scm`

**System details:**

- macOS Catalina - 10.15.6
- Default Mac Terminal app - Version 2.10
- MIT/GNU Scheme running under OS X
- The text editor I use is Atom - 1.50.0

### Question Edit #1 (Based on answer below)

I tried following instructions but this is complicated.

This is what I did:

1. Run `mit-scheme < /Users/Desktop/code.scm`
   [image]
2. After this I ran `mit-scheme --edit` to open Edwin. I tried to use the code inside of the `code.scm` file but it doesn't recognize it. This is the code in `code.scm` file:
   [image]

**This is what I want to be able to do:**
Notice in this picture, I can type a command, press enter and it automatically runs command. However, I want to be able to call `(fib 5)` and it references the function in `code.scm` file.
[image]

Could someone explain step by step how to do this? It's confusing looking at documentation for scheme websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a built-in `load` procedure available in the MIT Scheme REPL.
Evaluating

```
(load "path/to/file.scm")
```

causes the Scheme file located at *path/to/file.scm* to be evaluated at the top level (note that the double quotes around the file name are required).

And, as it turns out, this same function can be used to *reload* a file.
With this in mind, a possible "workflow" might look like this:

- Create new source file
- Evaluate `(load "path/to/file.scm")` in the REPL
- Edit source file
- Evaluate `(load "path/to/file.scm")` in the REPL
- ...etc.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a built-in "reload" procedure.
But...if you find yourself reloading a lot (as I imagine you will), you can always quickly write your own at the beginning of a hacking session:

```
(define (reload)
  (load "path/to/file.scm"))
```

And then just call `(reload)` whenever you make a change to your source file.

If you're interesting in using Emacs, I'd say it's worth a shot.
There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's not as steep as it looks up front :)

Also, I cannot recommend the [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) programming language(s) enough.
There is an incredibly straightforward way to set it up for SICP, and it's a much more forgiving environment than Emacs.
Let me know if you are interested and want any help getting started.

Comment: Thank you for giving step-by-step instructions! This is exactly what I was looking for! Does Emacs make all of this easier here? Meaning that I can have a REPL and source file in sync and not have to keep calling reload every time I change the source file?

Comment: My pleasure! And Emacs does make it alot easier, at least once you get used to it. What I typically do (and I think this is pretty universal) is split Emacs into two screens down the middle with a source file in one and the REPL in the other. Then, after making any edits, you can press Ctrl+C followed by Ctrl+C again to load the file into the REPL _and_ switch to the REPL window. Then play around in the REPL for a little bit, return to the source file, and repeat. Hitting Ctrl+C twice is magnitudes faster for me than switching windows and typing in an entire command/procedure.

Comment: Accepted answer! Thank you so much again! I will try to use Emacs with split screen with Scheme. Hopefully easy to do. It would be cool to do this with Edwin but it seems it's not possible and have to use Emacs

Answer (score 1):

You should use emacs with [xscheme.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExScheme).  It works much better.

If you continue as you do, you can also do `mit-scheme < code.scm`  or `mit-scheme --edit code.scm` and you will also get a [`*repl*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/testing/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-REPL-Mode.html) buffer inside [edwin](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Edwin.html).

I recommend you the emacs way, however.

Comment: Thank you for answering. For learning purposes, I'm trying out both methods you describe here. I ran `mit-scheme < code.scm` in terminal which causes it to display what was in my file and then ended with `End of input stream reached`. No REPL was provided. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @JEL at the link I provided you can read how to activate the repl buffer in edwin. M-x repl.

Comment: hm I tried, but this is hard. Could you see my updated question with notes? I explain how I tried your solution. Please see: `Question Edit #1` above

Comment: @JEL  I am sorry, there are lots of tutorials on the web about how to use mit-scheme.  You should ask a new question, not update the same question.  I provided enough links to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for response. This is a common pattern I see on Stack Overflow where people update their questions with more information. It was not a new question, instead it just made my initial question more clear. I think people like this pattern so Stack Overflow is not spammed. Thank you again for helping!

Answer (score 1):

A `(load "/path/to/file")` command should be available to you within [MIT Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) and the Edwin editor it comes with. However, I would actually recommend that you use [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), and use [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) within that to access both the REPL and to help with scheme file editing. It also makes dealing with various Scheme REPLs such as [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), [MIT Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Chicken](http://call-cc.org/), [Gambit](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [Chibi Scheme](http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/) fairly effortless. The same `(load "/path/to/file")` command would then be available to you within the REPL running under [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/), within [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but is generally much more powerful and seamless than when using the "naked" REPL. [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is very well tuned to use with Scheme and LISP. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate entire buffer: [press M-o](http://web.mit.edu/benmv/6.001/www/bpe/edwin.txt) (M is Alt on Windows). When in source file window, press it. It will evaluate the entire buffer i.e. (re)load the entire source file (without even saving it first). I found it by *googling "mit scheme edwin tutorial"*. Edwin is kind of Emacs itself.

[This page](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall05/ai/scheme/topten.html) says: "C-c C-s when done in a scheme-mode buffer [i.e. Scheme source file window], will switch to the Scheme interaction buffer [i.e. REPL]". i.e. you [press C-x C-s to save file](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/cheat-sheet.pdf), M-o to evaluate (i.e. load), C-c C-s to switch to the REPL.

If you've split your screen with `C-x 2` between a source file buffer and the REPL ("interactions buffer"), you can switch between them by pressing `C-x o` (for "go to the other window").