# How to scroll up to last entry in mit-scheme REPL?

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop, mit-scheme

I'm learning `scheme` programming from [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) textbook. I'm very new in `scheme`. I have installed [REPL](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) for this. I don't know, How to scroll up in `REPL`?

**For example:**

```
1 ]=> (define x 5)

;Value: x

1 ]=> x

;Value: 5
```

Now when I tied to scroll up value with **up** arrow key, I got some unexpected result. It is shown here:

```
1 ]=> ^[[A
```

can anyone tell me basic of how to use **scheme interpreter**? Thanks.

Comment: No. ctrl-p doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is not one Scheme interpreter since there are numerous implementations. What you are looking for is readline support.

mit-scheme doesn't have it but if you are using a *nix system you can install [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/) and start your interpreter with `rlwrap scheme` and using arrow keys will work. Note that this can give history features to all programs, not just a scheme interpreter.

There are other implementations that come with readline support included, [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org/), [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/), and [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). Probably a lot more. They aren't always loaded by default so search the documentation on how to enable it.

If you are using a graphical operating system, like Windows, Gnome/KDE, or OSX using [DrRacket](http://www.racket-lang.org/) with the [SICP support language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561746/1565698) would give you more options on how to edit, run and even debug your programs.