# How to run Picture language examples of SICP /scheme in repl?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm beginner in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). I'm reading section [2.2.4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.4), *A Picture Language*. I'm stuck with it's example. I didn't understand, How to run these examples?

As given in book, **wave** is supposed to be a primitive procedure. But When I tried to execute it, *REPL* throw an error as given below

```
1 ]=> wave

;Unbound variable: wave
```

Similarly when I tried to execute first example of this section, *REPL* throw an error

```
1 ]=> (define wave2 (beside wave (flip-vert wave)))

;Unbound variable: wave
```

I didn't understand, what's going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to type `painter`, not `primitive`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [DrRacket IDE](http://racket-lang.org/) there is a [SICP compatibility language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html?q=sicp#%28part._.Introduction_to_the__lang_sicp_language%29). Using DrRacket helps format code, identify errors and it has a debugger. It also supports standard Scheme as well as it's own dialect, racket, which is very similar but has lots of libraries like most modern languages.

**To install (after you have installed DrRacket)**

From terminal run:

```
raco pkg install sicp
```

You get lots of output and perhaps some WARNINGS. Restart DrRacket and replace `#lang racket` with `#lang sicp`. To get the picture language add `(#%require sicp-pict)`, thus this example should work nicely:

```
#lang sicp
(#%require sicp-pict)

(paint-hires  (below (beside diagonal-shading
                             (rotate90 diagonal-shading))
                     (beside (rotate270 diagonal-shading)
                             (rotate180 diagonal-shading))))
```

This is a short version of an answer to [Which lang packet is proper for SICP in Dr.Racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561746/1565698)

Comment: If you're like me and want to add your own image, the `(bitmap->painter ...)` procedure from `sicp-pict` lets you do that.   So you could do something like `(rotate180 (bitmap->painter "mypic.jpg"))`