# How to install sicp package module in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm newbie in programming world. I'm using **ubuntu** OS. I have started my journey with [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) book. I'm working with `scheme repl`. But suddenly I get stuck with section [2.2.4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.4)

I'm not able to execute it's example with `scheme repl`. I tried to run given example of section, I got an error as given below

```
1 ]=> (define wave2 (beside wave (flip-vert wave)))

;Unbound variable: wave
```

Even In book, **painter** is given as primitive procedure.
when I ran it, it thrown an error too

```
1 ]=> painter

;Unbound variable: painter
```

I don't know, where I'm doing mistake? can I run these example with **scheme repl**?

I have installed **racket** to solve this problem, But I'm not able to install sicp package for it. I was following these [instruction](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html#%28part._.Introduction_to_the_.S.I.C.P_.Picture_.Language%29). Unfortunately I didn't get that well. How can install these package?

Please give your suggestion to  solve this problem.

Comment: If you can't be more specific than "didn't get that well", it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help. Did the installation fail? Did installation succeed, but `(require sicp-pict)` in the REPL fails? Did both succeed, but using anything in `sicp-pict` fails? Something else?

Comment: (require sicp-pict) fail in repl.
Here is an error :
```> (require sicp-pict)
stdin::9: sicp-pict: standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  collection: "sicp-pict"
  in collection directories:
   /home/rishi/.racket/5.3.6/collects
   /usr/share/racket/collects
  in: sicp-pict
  context...:
   standard-module-name-resolver
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which lang packet is proper for SICP in Dr.Racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546115/which-lang-packet-is-proper-for-sicp-in-dr-racket)

Answer (score 3):

Use DrRacket to install the sicp package like this:

Open the Package Manager: in DrRacket choose the menu "File" then choose "Package Manager...".

In the tab "Do What I Mean" find the text field and enter: "sicp"

Finally click the "Install" button.

Test it. Make sure DrRacket has "Determine language from source" in the bottom left corner. Write the following program and click run:

#lang sicp

(inc 42)

The expected output is 43.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you probably need to do, here.

First: you need to install the `sicp` package. You can do this from the command-line, as other posts indicate, but the easiest way is probably to use DrRacket's package manager. Fortunately, the documentation for the sicp package describes how to do this:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html

After installing the sicp package, it sounds like the right solution is to use the "Racket Language" language, and start your file with

`#lang sicp`

Again, the documentation for the sicp package goes into a bit more detail here.

Let us know if this doesn't work!

EDIT: are you perhaps using a very old version of DrRacket? Pre-6.2, say?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of DrRacket. You need to upgrade DrRacket in order to install the sicp package.

If you cannot upgrade to a more recent version you should try the laternative, that is to use the planet package version of SICP. Look at my answer on [how to use SICP with DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561746/1565698) for both new and old versions of Racket.