# SICP 1.25 interpreter issue

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

1) DrRacket

2) https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp15/assets/interpreter/scheme.html

Using both of the interpreters above for Hacker's version with arguments `(expmod 11 17 17)` yields different answers. 11 for DrRacket (as the procedure should) and 0 for inst.eecs.berkeley.edu

Included is an example evaluation at the bottom.  Substituting for all `(< base m)` into both interpreters yields different answers when using inst.eecs.berkeley.edu and therefore makes the entire timed-prime-test fail for this interpreter.

My question: What is the underlying issue with this interpreter? Is this problem due to an error in interpretation? A different method for evaluation between the two?

```
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (remainder (fast-expt base exp) m))
(define (fast-expt b n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((even? n) (square (fast-expt b (/ n 2))))
        (else (* b (fast-expt b (- n 1))))))
(define (even? n)
  (= (remainder n 2) 0))
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(remainder (fast-expt 11 17) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (fast-expt 11 16)) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (fast-expt 11 8))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (fast-expt 11 4)))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square (fast-expt 11 2))))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square (square (fast-expt 11 1)))))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square (square (* 11 (fast-expt 11 0))))))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square (square (* 11 1)))))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square (square 11))))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square (square 121)))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square (square 14641))) 17)
(remainder (* 11 (square 214358881)) 17)
(remainder (* 11 45949729863572161) 17)
(remainder 505447028499293771 17)
```

A link to online SICP

https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#call_footnote_Temp_78

Comment: Note that `expmod` computes the power `p=base^exp` first, then finds the modulo. This means that the temporary result `p` can be very large. So large that it can't be represented exactly using floating point. Instead you must write a variation of your `fast-expt` that computes the modulo of each temporary result. In this way all numbers in the computation will be below the modulo - and you will get the correct result also in the Berkeley Scheme implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while DrRacket has a [SICP language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546115/which-lang-packet-is-proper-for-sicp-in-dr-racket) where SICP code should work Racket's default language is not compatible with Scheme. It's close so the two languages have more in common than Java and C#, but they are to be acknowledged as different languages. 
Racket has support for Scheme. Both `#!r5rs` and `#!r6rs`.

Your online intepreter might just have basic Scheme functionality and perhaps only floating point numbers. Only R7RS requires the full numeric tower so large numbers might become floats. A very easy test by me revealed that the number became inexact very fast:

```
(/ 1 2) ; ==> 0.5
```

With a full numeric tower the answer would be the rational exact number `1/2`. Evalutation `call/cc`, and `exact->inexact` gave an error so the interpreter does not meet the requirement for the standard scheme reports.

You need to read the documentation and features of your [chosen implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scheme_(programming_language)_implementations) since your program might depend on features that are not included everywhere. If I implemented a curly language that had elementary support for some Java bindings it would still not be a Java implementation since it would be incomplete.